# Do the points lie on the same plane?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

I want to check if the four points of $\mathbb{R}^3$ $$P=(1,2,2), \ Q=(3,5,6), \ R=(1,3,2), \ S=(5,2,3)$$ lie on one plane.

For that do we have to take three points, to define the plane and check if the forth point is on that plane?

For that do we do the following ?

We consider the points $P,Q,R$.

$\vec{n}$, the normal vector to the plane is defined as $\vec{n}=\vec{PQ}\times \vec{PR}$, i.e. we have $\vec{n}=(2,3,4)\times(0,1,0)=(-4, 0, 2)$.

The equation of the plane is \begin{align*}n_x(x-P_x)+n_y(y-P_y)+n_z(z-P_z)=0 &\Rightarrow -4\cdot (x-1)+0\cdot (y-2)+2\cdot (z-2)=0 \\ & \Rightarrow -4x+4+2z-4=0 \\ & \Rightarrow z=2x\end{align*} The point $S$ doesn't satisfy this equation, that means that te four points don't lie on the same plane.

Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: We don't "have to" use that solution method, but your method is valid.

Comment: Thank you!!! :-)

Comment: If $(-4,0,2)$ is a normal vector so is $(-2,0,1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Equivalently, you may check directly that
$$\begin{align}\det\left(\overrightarrow{PQ},\overrightarrow{PR},\overrightarrow{PS}\right)
&=\begin{vmatrix}2&0&4\\3&1&0\\4&0&1\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\begin{vmatrix}2&4\\4&1\end{vmatrix}\\
&=-14\ne0.\end{align}$$

Comment: Why should the determinant be zero so that the points are on the same plane?

Comment: @MaryStar Because if your 4 points lie in a plane (in the algebraic geometric sense of a solution set to a single linear equation in 3 variables), these 3 vectors will span a plane (in the linear algebra sense of a 2-dimensional subspace), and thus be linearly dependent.

Comment: @MaryStar note that if you develop this determinant along the last column (instead of the second column or row as I did), you will do *exactly the same* computations as you wrote in your post.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!!! :-)